# Hyperelliptic modular curves in characteristic p

Tags: nt.number-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry

Ogg characterized the finitely many N such that $X_0(N)_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is hyperelliptic, and Poonen proved in "Gonality of modular curves in characteristic p" that for large enough N, $X_0(N)_{\mathbb{F}_p}$ is not hyperelliptic.

**Question**: Are there any N such that $X_0(N)_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is not hyperelliptic but for some p not dividing N $X_0(N)_{\mathbb{F}_p}$ is hyperelliptic?

I'm also interested in this question for other modular curves of the form $X_H$, where H is a congruence subgroup.

Comment: Somewhat relevant: http://arxiv.org/abs/0811.0876

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I already gave the currently accepted answer to this question around 10 years ago. And the answer can be summarised as "Yes, here is an example". However, after 10 years I wanted to come back to this question and answer it again, but now in the opposite direction. Namely, as it turns out the example that I found above is the only example. To be more precise:

**Theorem.** Let $N$ be a positive integer, $p$ a prime not dividing $N$, and $X_H$ a modular curve with of level N corresponding to a congruence subgroup $\Gamma_1(N) \subseteq H \subseteq \Gamma_0(N)$. Suppose that $X_{H,\mathbb F_p}$ is hyperelliptic but $X_{H, \mathbb Q}$ is not, then $p=2$, $N=37$ and $H$ is the congruence subgroup generated by $\Gamma_1(N)$ and $d_4$ where $d_4$ is a matrix representing the diamond operator $\langle 4 \rangle$.

This is Theorem 1.3 of https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.04864. In that theorem, the hyperellipticity is considered over $\overline {\mathbb F}_p$ and $\mathbb C$. However, since all the curves $X_H$ under consideration have a rational point, they are hyperelliptic over $\mathbb F_p$ if and only if they are $\overline {\mathbb F}_p$ and similar over $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb C$.

The proof is consisting of two steps, the first one is using the Castelnuovo-Severi inequality to establish an apriori upper bound on $N$, see Proposition 3.6 of loc. cit. The second step is checking for hyperellipticity by looking at the space of quadrics that vanish on the image of the canonical map, as in my other answer.

Answer (score 7):

A curve $C$ is hyperelliptic if and only if the canonical map $C \to \mathbb P^*(\Omega^1(C))$, which sends a point $p$ to the codimension 1 subspace $V_p \subset\Omega^1(C)$ of all one forms vanishing at $p$, is a two to one map. In the hyperelliptic case its image will be a $\mathbb P^1$, and the degree two map will be the quotient by the hyperelliptic involution. The map $\mathbb P^1 \to \mathbb P^*(\Omega^1(C))$ will basically be a Veronese embedding and hence its image will lie on a lot of quadrics. One can use this to search for possible candidates. I found none for $\Gamma_0(N)$ with $N \leq 151$. I think my search is provably complete, showing that for $N \leq 151$ and all $p$ the only hyperelliptic $X_0(N)_{\mathbb F_p}$ are the ones who are already hyperelliptic over $\mathbb Q$. Together with the general bound $${\rm gon_{\mathbb F_p^2}} X_0(N) \geq [PSL_2(\mathbb Z) : \Gamma_0(N)]\frac {p-1} {12(p^2+1)}$$ which is mentioned in Poonen's paper this implies that $X_0(N)_{\mathbb F_p}$ will never be hyperelliptic modulo $2,3$ or $5$ unless of course $X_0(N)_{\mathbb Q}$ is.
Now for $N \geq 151$ the genus of $X_0(N)$ already starts to become reasonably big. So I would not expect there to be any examples with $p>5$ and $N>151$ either. But I don't see how to prove it yet since Poonen's bound depends heavily on $p$.

Using this idea for $X_H$ with other congruence subgroups $H$ I found an example though. There might be more but this is just the first one I found. Anyway here is the explicit example:
Consider the modular curve $X_1(37)/\langle 4\rangle$, it is a double cover of $X_0(37)$ and its genus is $4$. Its global one forms are generated by the modular forms with q-expansion:
\begin{gather}
x_0 := q - 2q^{5} + 2q^{6} - 3q^{7} + 2q^{9} + O(q^{10})\\
x_1 := q^{2} - q^{5} - q^{6} + O(q^{10})\\
x_2 := q^{3} - 2q^{7} + O(q^{10})\\
x_3 := q^{4} - q^{5} + q^{6} - 2q^{7} + 2q^{9} + O(q^{10}).\\
\end{gather}
These satisfy the relations:
\begin{gather}
- x_{1}^{2} + x_{0} x_{2} - 2 x_{2} x_{3} = 0 \\
x_{1}^{2} x_{2} - 2 x_{1} x_{2}^{2} + 2 x_{2}^{3} -  x_{0} x_{1} x_{3} +
x_{1}^{2} x_{3} + x_{1} x_{2} x_{3} - 4 x_{2}^{2} x_{3} -  x_{0}
x_{3}^{2} + x_{1} x_{3}^{2} + 4 x_{2} x_{3}^{2} + 2 x_{3}^{3} = 0, \\
\end{gather}
which describe the canonical model $X_1(37)/\langle 4\rangle $ as the intersection of a smooth quadric and cubic in $\mathbb P^3$.
Modulo $2$ however $x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3$ satisfy two additional relations:
$$
x_{1} x_{2} + x_{2}^{2} + x_{0} x_{3} + x_{2} x_{3} =0 \\
x_{2}^{2} + x_{1} x_{3} + x_{2} x_{3} = 0,\\
$$
which shows that in this case the image of the canonical embedding is a $\mathbb P^1$. 2 is the only prime for which it happens for $X_1(37)/\langle 4 \rangle$.

Answer (score 6):

This is sort of a cheap answer, but I would look at values of N where X_0(N) has genus 3 and is not hyperelliptic (over Q).  In genus 3, the locus of hyperelliptic curves has codimension 1 in the whole moduli space of curves, so one would expect a non-hyperelliptic curve to reduce to a hyperelliptic curve mod p for some finite (but typically non-empty) set of primes p.

Presumably this could be made explicit:  a non-hyperelliptic genus 3 curve is a plane quartic, and so you've got to figure that there is an invariant F of ternary quartic forms with the property that F(P) is a multiple of precisely those primes where the curve cut out by P reduces to a hyperelliptic curve.  Or so I would guess.

Comment: Noam Elkies discusses the case of the Klein quartic reducing to an hyperelliptic curve in characteristic 7, see The Klein quartic in number theory, p. 82.

Comment: True, though this is $X(7)$, not $X_0(N)$, 
and its hyperelliptic characterstic is $7$ itself.
Apropos JSE's answer, I was thinking the same thing,
and found in my fields the case of $X_0(183)/\langle w_3,w_{61}\rangle$
which is a quartic plane curve that becomes hyperelliptic mod $2$.
Unfortunately it seems that this won't work for the curves $X_0(N)$
themselves, because the only quartic curve among then is $X_0(43)$
and that curve doesn't happen to become hyperelliptic modulo any 
$p \neq 43$.


Comment: Thanks for the responses! I had tried the genus 3 suggestion for $X_1(N)$ and didn't find any examples with $p \nmid N$. (I only did $X_1(N)$ rather than $X_0$ because I had the equations on hand; I'll try it for $X_0$ too.)

Comment: You're welcome. 
(Typo: $X_0(43)$ is the only quartic curve among *them*, not "then".)
The reason these curves are mostly hyperelliptic to begin with is that
they have automorphisms such as $w_d$, and when $X_0(N)$ has genus as low
as $3$ there's usually some quotient $X_0(N)/w_d$ of genus zero.
The curves $X_1(N)$ have even more automorphisms and thus might be
even more prone to being hyperelliptic for this reason.

Comment: The curve $X_0(64)$ is also a plane quartic (it is the Fermat quartic), but it doesn't work.

Comment: You're right $-$ I missed that one (though I've long known that example)
because I looked only at page 1 of Antwerp Table V =
http://modular.math.washington.edu/Tables/antwerp/table5/small_136.jpg
which goes up to $N \leq 60$...

Comment: BTW 15+ years ago Allan Adler showed that remarkably $X(11)$
has extra automorphisms in characteristic $3$, with group 
$M_{11}$ instead of $PSL_2({\bf Z}/11{\bf Z})$. 
But none of those is hyperelliptic either.  
(Likewise for $X(7)$ in characteristic $3$,
where it is isomorphic with the Fermat quartic
and has more automorphisms than either curve does in characteristic zero.)